# Piecewise Operation on List of Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, coding-efficiency

My question is, can I make a function or variable that can perform an on operation or numpy method on each np.array element within a list in a more succinct way than what I have below (preferably by just calling one function or variable)?

#### Generating the list of arrays:

```
import numpy as np
array_list = [np.random.rand(3,3) for x in range(5)]
array_list
```

#### Current Technique of operating on each element:

My current method (as seen below) involves unpacking it and doing something to it:

```
[arr.std() for arr in array_list]

[arr + 2 for arr in array_list]
```

#### Goal:

My hope it to get something that could perform the operations above by simply typing:

```
x.std()
```

or

```
x +2
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use an actual NumPy array and perform your operations over the desired axes, instead of having them stuffed in a list.

```
actual_array = np.array(array_list)

actual_array.std(axis=(1, 2))
# array([0.15792346, 0.25781021, 0.27554279, 0.2693581 , 0.28742179])
```

If you generally wanted all axes except the first, this could be something like `tuple(range(1, actual_array.ndim))` instead of explicitly specifying the tuple.